# Rails image_tag not using CDN Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, cdn

I've recently setup a CDN for my application, almost everything works fine, like my static assets, my JS and CSS.

But some object assets (images) keep using my S3 URL to fetch the data from, for example:

```
<%= image_tag(@listing.cover.url(:large))%>
```

Becomes, in production:

```
<img src="https://musicjungle.s3.amazonaws.com/listing_covers/5045/large.jpg?1484594254" class="fotorama__img" style="width: 548px; height: 548px; left: 91px; top: 0px;">
```

Instead of using my CDN. For the record, here is the piece of my production.rb where I setup the CDN:

```
#CDN settings
config.action_controller.asset_host = "d1bfllp5zjnl7u.cloudfront.net"
```

As I described, all my other assets are rendered without problem, but those still use the S3. Maybe this is related to an attachment helper that I have? I created one to upload the images of the application to the S3, here is the code:

```
module Shared
  module AttachmentHelper

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def has_attachment(name, options = {})

        # generates a string containing the singular model name and the pluralized attachment name.
        # Examples: "user_avatars" or "asset_uploads" or "message_previews"
        attachment_owner    = self.table_name.singularize
        attachment_folder   = "#{attachment_owner}_#{name.to_s.pluralize}"

        # we want to create a path for the upload that looks like:
        # message_previews/00/11/22/001122deadbeef/thumbnail.png
        attachment_path     = "#{attachment_folder}/:id/:style.:extension"

        if Rails.env.production?
          options[:path]            ||= attachment_path
          options[:storage]         ||= :s3
          options[:s3_credentials]  ||= {
            :bucket => 'bucket-name',
            :access_key_id => 'KEY_ID',
            :secret_access_key => 'ACCESS_KEY'
          }
          options[:s3_permissions]  ||= 'private'
          options[:s3_protocol]     ||= 'https'
          options[:s3_headers]      ||= { 
            'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000', 
            'Expires' => 10.years.from_now.httpdate 
          } 
        else
          # For local Dev/Test envs, use the default filesystem, but separate the environments
          # into different folders, so you can delete test files without breaking dev files.
          options[:path]  ||= ":rails_root/public/system/attachments/#{Rails.env}/#{attachment_path}"
          options[:url]   ||= "/system/attachments/#{Rails.env}/#{attachment_path}"
        end

        # pass things off to paperclip.
        has_attached_file name, options
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the [`s3_host_alias`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/b01f47407a03feabd41ac8786b577310e3be87b6/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb#L65-L67) option in your Paperclip options:

```
options[:s3_host_alias] = "d1bfllp5zjnl7u.cloudfront.net"
```